# How to simulate streaming radio listeners?

Tags: load, simulation, audio-streaming, internet-radio

How to simulate streaming radio listeners?
I have an online radio setup streaming at port 5672 and at url like domain.com:5672/radio.mp3
I want to test the website/server/ram/bandwidth/load etc for this server

How would i do that for an mp3 extension file? browsers dont work!

I tried using webrunner, but it cannot ""listen"" to mp3 ... it tries to download it!
I cannot open multiple winamp sessions ...
for like 2000 listeners

Please let me know.
Thanks and Regards
prad

Answer (score 2):

What I do is call WGET and have it output to `/dev/null` or `NUL` on windows.  Here is my windows command line:

```
wget.exe -O NUL -q http://domain.com:5672/radio.mp3
```

I then make a shortcut for this and set it to run minimized.  This allows me to smack <kbd>enter</kbd> a few hundred times and watch the listener counts.  You could easily script this to get a specific number, but I've found it handy to manually turn up the listener count.

Be sure that you actually have enough bandwidth for this test.  In other words... you will probably need to be local to the server.  Also, it is good to fire up one stream in Winamp or VLC so that you can hear/watch the buffer drop.  Some servers will maintain a connection, but will be unable to keep up with the flow.

Answer (score -1):

Shoutcast generally isn't that CPU or i/o intensive even at higher bit rates with a lot of listeners, bandwidth however is always going to be your concern. Anyway can use mpg123 on Linux to test load.

> mpg123 -p URL -t -q &

The following tools might also help work out your bandwidth requirements:

http://servers.internet-radio.com/tools/bandwidth/

Comment: There is no reason to decode the audio to test load on an internet radio.  In fact, this will cause significant load for whatever is doing the decoding, and will skew your test results.